# Visual Studio 2017 Python Feature Addition Issue

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

I want to install python for Visual Studio 2017 and to do that i launched the visual studio installer using this link [image]

After it opens it goes to this window
[image]

After clicking update it comes back to same update window not sure how to solve this problem i even tried with launching direct VS2017 setup that didn't help either...please let me know if anyone has seen this issue and next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install all the tool required  for developping with Python using Visual Studio 2017, you need to to launch your Visual Studio Installer corresponding to your edition of Visual Studio.
Then you can add the workload in order to install everything required to code with python.